# Bonding (solid 6ga bare) wire from supplemental grounding electrode to main GEC -- can they not be spliced?

Tags: electrical

This is just a hypothetical....If you have a 6ga solid copper from the bar in the panel to an outside ground rod, can you or not splice another pc of 6ga solid copper from the current 6ga wire to go to another rod? Why is it said that is has to be one single run of wire? Are connections just not safe when splices are installed on 6ga bare copper ground, or what am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: They can be spliced, but the splices must be of a type that cannot be undone, welding/non-removable splice.  Usually just easier to use or replace with a single wire long enough.  Might be cheaper also.

Answer (score 6):

They can be spliced if the splice is "irreversible" which is either Cadweld or compression/crimp.

The compression splices are not expensive, the crimping tool is, but you might be able to rent one.

A cadweld "one-shot" (non-reusable mold) might or might not come out cheaper then renting the crimper. A really well-stocked rental might have reusable (graphite) cadweld molds and clamps to rent.

Comment: So things like split bolts won't hold, I guess.....mine is a single solid run, but when doing it, I just wondered why people were saying that it couldn't be spliced, etc...Appreciate the info.

Comment: @Brad  It is more that regular run of the mill removable splices that homeowners have handy are not allowed.

Comment: They are looking for "utterly reliable connection for 100 years or more" on this specific conductor run. All other grounds can be normally spliced, this specific one code is looking for a higher standard.

Comment: See Harper's answer - a split bolt to bond a wire from a second rod, that doesn't require the GEC to be cut seems like it may be OK.

Answer (score 4):

What you can't do is cut the wire in order to put all 3 into a splice.  The run to the first rod must be continuous.

The run to the 2nd rod can go to the first rod (usually easy) or to the panel.

Feel free to swap "1st rod" and "2nd rod" in my meaning if your topology is different.

As a general rule, one can splice a Grounding Electrode Conductor without cutting it, using a split bolt.  However I don't think that's allowed on the run to the 2nd ground rod.

(Armand edit) From a Feb 2022 Mike Holt's Forum answer:

> 250.53(A)(2) Supplemental Electrode Required. A single rod, pipe, or plate electrode shall be supplemented by an additional electrode of a type specified in 250.52(A)(2) through (A)(8).
> The supplemental electrode shall be permitted to be bonded to one of the following:
> (1) Rod, pipe, or plate electrode
> (2) Grounding electrode conductor
> (3) Grounded service-entrance conductor
> (4) Nonflexible grounded service raceway
> (5) Any grounded service enclosure